# How to treat pending flags?

Tags: discussion, flags

When I started reviewing my pending flags, I noticed that there are some flags marked as active for now already a year.

Is it legit to flag them again for moderator attention, stating in short sentence, why it was flagged a year ago, and that flag is still active but anyway the flagged post hasn't changed anything since then? I did so. And got all of them marked as helpful.

But now I struggled on a post, where I would say in respect of the now existing flag options, a post is on-topic, which was ~ 1year ago off-topic.

So I'm asking now:

1. Is it OK to flag posts for moderator attention which seem to be got lost in the flag queue?
2. If there are flags which are pending for such a long time, and nowadays they seem to be respecting rules which didn't exist to that time, should I flag for moderator attention with a request to decline my flags?

Or what else could/should I do?

Comment: Closing flags go into the mighty big Close Vote review queue. It can take a while. You cannot reflag any posts you *already flagged*. Just leave any posts already flagged, they'll get handled eventually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So it is normal that some flags take eventually more then a year to review, even if it is clearly off-topic?

Comment: I'm afraid so..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even other flags?

Comment: @lozadaOmr: 'other' flags are only handled by moderators; they have a backlog too though.