# Flag has been active for months

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23017816/3) April 11 at 16:44

It has since been edited and answered. However, the flag shows up in my list as Active. I would think the status would be something else as a result of the question being edited. Is it suppose to be `Active` still or should it be something else?

I read [How to treat pending flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266343/how-to-treat-pending-flags), but it seems like this might be a different case where the question was edited (which I think is supposed to remove flags?)

[image]

Comment: What did you flag it as?

Comment: I believe it was an "Other" flag. I don't know why I didn't flag it as VLQ, but it says "unclear what you're asking". I think that's a custom reason, but I don't remember.

Comment: Yup, it's supposed to be. I have had 'Other' flags sit around for months as well; they're the ones that require an explicit moderator action. It's somewhat annoying sometimes when it's about an issue that isn't relevant anymore after some time but that's how it is. Definitely try to avoid it when there are specific flags for it, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I've placed 100 moderator attention flags, of which there are 20 waiting for review, so I hope these flags automatically expire as well.

Comment: I've got 50+ flags "waiting for review"

Comment: Only a few months?  My oldest flags that are still active date back to June 2009, so that's 5 years and counting.  :D

Comment: these are my oldest active flags [image](http://i.imgur.com/68HdGzc.png?1)

Comment: [Why does it take so long to review a flag suggested by a user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174259/238586)

Answer (score 50):

That is a recommend closure flag. Those are not visible to moderators; they will only ever push a question into the Close Votes queue for review. Moderators also have no direct way of dismissing them as helpful or declined.

From what I can tell, a *single* flag of this type will not actually push the question into the Close Votes queue (I think the threshold might be set to 2 on Stack Overflow). You currently hold the only pending close flag on that question. It has never had a review task created for it and thus never had any chance to be dismissed through review. The *only* indirect way I, as a moderator, can handle the flag is to actually close the question. We have absolutely no ability to manually dismiss these.

I really wish they'd think of some better way of dealing with these flags that are sitting around forever. This flag could *literally* sit there forever, since nobody on the site is capable of handling it.

Comment: I think we have to clear all of the existing close /review tasks before we'll see all of the posts with only one close flag. So yes, this literally could take forever.

Comment: An idea is to expire flags after 6 months if only one vote remains.

Comment: So why don't thy make an option so we can cancel our own flags ?

Comment: @staticx - That definitely doesn't seem like the right solution to me. Bad content should be removed as promptly as possible, even if it's not frequently trafficked. Maybe we have an expiration based on a certain number of people who can vote to close it visiting the question and not making a vote to close it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard well, then there is or will be a correct procedure to report this flags ?

Comment: As I also stated [in this other comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276919/duplicate-flag-unresolved-and-forgotten#comment817573_276923) these flags now age away if not handled.