# "question may already have an answer" message visible even after several months

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446377/1438393) back in May. Back then, someone had flagged it as a duplicate, and since then, "*This question may already have an answer here*" message is displayed on the top of the question:

[image]

It's been 3 months and 4 days since the question was asked, but the message is still visible (to me, that is). The flag expired (none are listed when you click on the *Flag* button), and the message shouldn't be displayed, should it?

For more information, please see [this conversation](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/possible-bug-in-the-matrix) I had with [♦ Anna Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/anna-lear) in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: I think you are the only one seeing that banner.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, that's correct. But why am I seeing it?

Comment: Because you are the OP.  The banner is raised when a close as duplicate vote is registered, so that the question asker can find their potential answer quickly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm aware of that, but I don't see any duplicate close-votes on the question — why is the banner still displayed?

Comment: Hmm, there's an active "recommend closure as duplicate" flag, but it's not showing up in the dashboard.  I'll poke a community manager.

Comment: I'll take a look at this and/or pass it on to someone else.

Comment: @Robert Those only go to the Close Votes queue. Problem is with only one flag, it is not eligible to have a task created for it (currently, because of the queue's size), so there's no way for the flag to get cleared, ever. See [Flag has been active for months](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266842/flag-has-been-active-for-months).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've removed the flag, which should correct the *immediate* problem here.

Long-term, we probably shouldn't be displaying this notice in response to close *flags*. Unlike close votes, close flags cannot be retracted and don't age away - the flagger can delete the *comment* that indicates the duplicate (as was done in this case), but the flag (and notice) will remain. If the flag doesn't prompt the addition of a corresponding duplicate *vote*, then there's no reason to feature it in the UI.

We should also probably be [aging away close flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203670/dont-let-flag-to-close-flags-linger-for-months-in-flag-purgatory)....

Comment: Wouldn't they be resolved the moment a CQ-task had been created and run its course? If so, no need to age them...

Comment: Or better, make flags retractable.

Comment: @bjb568 We have several off-topic posts that have longstanding recommend closure flags against them, but no action has been taken against them.

Comment: Please make sure that such flags are "aged away", not "scheduledtaskinvalidated".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204263

Comment: @bjb568 Even if retractable, it's not likely that those users will come back and actually do so

Comment: @Izkata I'm talking about the case of the accidental or now-invalid flag that the user wants to retract. Not to replace aging away flags.