# Custom moderator flags stay active

Tags: support, flags

I have submitted four recent custom moderator flags (three remaining active):

> Aug 11 at 12:16 -- **active**
>   Aug 11 at 12:21 -- **active**
>   Aug 11 at 12:27 -- marked as helpful the *next day*
>   Aug 17 at 15:53 -- **active**

They were all based around the same topic (users making bad suggested edits) and were phrased in pretty much the same way, but one of them was marked as helpful while the rest remain active. I am aware that the moderator queue is large but flags remaining active for over two weeks seems strange especially since one flag was reviewed the next day.

*Why are these flags still active? Have they just been ignored or dismissed?*
*If it is just because of the size of the queue, why was the one flag reviewed so fast?*

---

Reasons why this is not another duplicate (that I could find):

- [These are not for recommending closure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266842/flag-has-been-active-for-months)
- [I see no actions taken on the active flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192811/why-is-this-automatic-flag-still-shown-as-active)
- [The flags seem to be going through review fairly quickly judging by how one was reviewed the next day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165545/how-long-can-a-flag-wait-for-review)
- I have barely any declined flags

Comment: You might rethink your third bullet point, as there are currently 971 flags pending.

Comment: @animuson Maybe I'm underestimating it. I just felt that it was strange how one was reviewed so fast and it might have caused me to exaggerate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those particular flags you cast take a while to process. The moderator probably saw it by working backwards in the queue (which we do sometimes) and then deciding not to look at the other ones just yet, or perhaps had to leave.

The flags queue has grown to quite a large amount the past week, so flag handling times are dwindling.