# Duplicate flag unresolved and forgotten?

Tags: support, status-completed

Once upon a long time ago I flagged a question as a duplicate of another (and it still is) and the flag still hasn't been accepted/decliened or otherwise resolved.

Here is the question: [c3p0 connection pool is not shrinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343741/c3p0-connection-pool-is-not-shrinking) and the duplicate: [c3p0 pool is not shrinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343530/c3p0-pool-is-not-shrinking)

My question is, How do I go about retracting the flag or otherwise getting it cleared? I couldn't find a way, or anything in meta or help that lead me to being able to resolve this myself.

Sorry if this seems silly but my OCD is bothering me (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens a lot with the recommend closure flags, and there's not anything you can do about it other than just leave it in your queue, since **it is not possible to manually retract a flag**.

Recommend closure flags only get dismissed under three conditions:

1. Another user votes to close the question, either from review or the question itself, *for the same reason you selected*. Dismisses as helpful.
2. The question gets closed or deleted at any point. Dismisses as helpful (whether it was closed for the reason you chose or not).
3. Reviewers choose to leave it open. Dismisses as declined.

Moderators *can* somewhat indirectly dismiss these flags, depending on the circumstances:

1. To mark it helpful, they can just close the question. This does however require that they agree it should be closed for *some reason*, which is harder for duplicates since that also requires some knowledge on the topic to determine it is actually a duplicate.
2. To decline the flag, they can view the timeline, visit the review item that was created, and then click the Leave Open button.

There is a huge problem with option two, though. Questions with only a single, really old recommend closure flag no longer have a review task for them. That means the second option to decline it is no longer available for us. If the question really *shouldn't* be closed, it is impossible to correctly dismiss the flag even as a moderator.

So users without the privilege to vote to close will sometimes find these lingering flags deep in their flag history that simply never get touched, because *no one ever looks at them*. Or more appropriately, they're not ever *shown* to anyone. They'll only get dismissed on the off-chance someone else stops by that question and votes to close it, or another user flags it and bumps it into the Close Votes queue (which may still take a while since that queue is massive).

Comment: I think this is outdated as it's possible to manually retract a flag now and closure flags also now age away.