# Why don't my flags get resolved?

Tags: discussion, flags

I have unresolved flags on Stack Overflow from days and even months ago. Are these ever going to get resolved or is there a threshold that after a few days they're as good as ignored?

Comment: What kind of flags?  If they are custom mod flags, it will periodically takes weeks, sometimes months, for them to be touched in the mod queue.

Comment: Mostly close flags. Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, 100% of your unresolved flags older than a few hours are close flags. As explained in JAL's answer below, those go into the close vote queue, and it can take a while for them to get resolved.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266842/flag-has-been-active-for-months, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276919/duplicate-flag-unresolved-and-forgotten

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Close flags will put the question into the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close).  That queue (as of writing) has over 9,700 questions in it.  If people don't review the question, the flag won't be handled.  I believe Close flags age away after two weeks, so it's also possible that after two weeks the question has not completed its review, and your flags age away.

PSA: Go through the queue and review some questions!

Comment: Shameless plug: If you are interested in helping get the queue size down, there are various cleanup efforts organized in chat, such as the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).  It's your Stack Overflow, don't trash it!