# Can you share flags when it is inactive for weeks/months?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, vote-to-close

I still have 2 flags still unreviewed and I already read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266842/flag-has-been-active-for-months) and I understand that not everyone is seeing all these flags being put.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672571/ubuntu-freeradius-log), I flagged it to be migrated with the words:

> This question is more suitable on Super User. Please migrate it. Not convinced? Look at the subject. Its not exactly programming, but still focused on computer hardware (or online network, whatever it is).

And in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640282/how-do-i-zoom-out-on-this-screen), I flagged it being off-topic because it had nothing to do with programming, even if the problem is relating to Visual Studio.

I feel like it's time to finally review these, but maybe we can do something better.

> We implement a system on Stack Overflow (only because it has the most traffic apart from [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)) that can share flags to moderators, or some "shout" function that can get the reviewers' attention (if there are any active) on the specific flag. And so to not make such a mess, the function will be available if the flag has been pending for a week or so, or maybe even months.

That's right! A sharing function for flags. Shall we have one?

Comment: @JeanneDark I don't think so. This is a [tag:feature-request] and I'm not asking when to use it. Instead, I'm asking if we can have the share option.

Comment: [People are not required to explain their downvotes.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) But generally downvotes on feature requests mean "I don't want this."

Comment: Honestly, both flags are false in my opinion. A question being off-topic here and _maybe_ on-topic there doesn't make it automatically a good migration option. There is a unwritten "don't migrate crap" rule, so I would only suggest migration when I know this question is good and worth the time. If not, then I just flag/vote to close the question as being off-topic. Regarding question two: it's not off-topic here, users skill can ask questions about programming tools.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

With a little over 1,000 users that are able to flag posts and only 24 poor souls to handle them, we're not giving the mob any more tools to team up against the under staffed mod team.

Except cases like spam and rude/abusive flags no immediate handling is needed. Nothing breaks if a flag isn't declined within 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Not only that, but a flag sharing site doesn't even help. The flag still would need a mod to review it no matter if some users talked about it or not. So it wouldn't improve the "flag handling time".

Comment: Also at least 25 percent are flags that either require a mod to do investigation thoroughly, or they are bad flags that should be declined.

Comment: Did you by any chance get that first number wrong by a magnitude of 1,000?

Comment: @Scratte Of course, there's a little over 1 user with the ability to flag

Comment: @Nick :D Wrong direction :D

Answer (score 5):

Moderators can already look at these pending flags if we want to. There's no need for a new system feature to "share" them with us.

The reason we aren't looking at them isn't because we can't see them. It's because we already have plenty of moderator-only flags to handle.

The community can handle flags recommending closure of questions. There are more of them than there are of us. Escalating issues from a large number of people to a small number of people is the reverse of what would be helpful.